# How do I sort a group of objects based on an element of the objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

The object collection is

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Each object has a number of elements in it as such

```
{value1: someValue, valueIWantToSort: someNumericValue, value2: someValue, value3: someValue,...}
```

Now I want to put the object in order based on the value of valueIWantToSort. Where valueIWantToSort is a number.

Comment: Array.prototype.sort...

Comment: your "group" is an array. you can use array methods to do this work.

Answer (score -2):

First of all the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), to read !

TL;DR : We use a comparator function passed to the native sort function of arrays !

```js
//[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object];
    /*
    {
        value1: someValue, 
        valueIWantToSort: someNumericValue, 
        value2: someValue, 
        value3: someValue,
    ...}
    */

var myArray=[];
var i=0;
for(i;i<10;i++){
  myArray.push({
        value1: 'someValue', 
        valueIWantToSort: Math.round(Math.random() *100 ) ,
        value2: 'someValue', 
        value3: 'someValue',
  });
};
document.body.innerHTML += "Before sorting :<br> " + JSON.stringify( myArray ) + "<hr>";

myArray.sort( function(a,b){ return  a.valueIWantToSort > b.valueIWantToSort })


document.body.innerHTML += "After sorting :<br> " + JSON.stringify( myArray ) + "<hr>";

myArray.sort( function(a,b){ return  a.valueIWantToSort < b.valueIWantToSort })
// here we invert the sort order -----------------------^

document.body.innerHTML += "After sorting inverted:<br> " + JSON.stringify( myArray );
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort` receives a `function` that must return a number, either below 0, 0 or greater than 0. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @arg20 and to be complete [Arithmetic_Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)